# При динамическом добавлении Node'а, нет стилей

Tags: javascript, html

Скажите пожалуйста, что делать тогда, когда при динамическом добавлении Node'а, на нём нет стилей, точнее в инспекторе кода они есть, а в инспекторе стилей и на самом экране нет?

```
var newNode='<div class="list col-sm" style="border: black;border-style: dashed;border-width: 1px;background-color: #00000012;"> My DIV </div>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(newNode, "text/xml").documentElement;

var stack = document.getElementById('lol');
//stack.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', doc);
stack.appendChild(doc);
```

Пробовал принудительно перерисовывать, но увы:

```
    function Force(){
        var element=$('#myfrm')
        var disp = element[0].style.display;
        element[0].style.display = 'none';
        var trick = element[0].offsetHeight;
        element[0].style.display = disp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы строку парсирили с флагом "text/xml", а в данном случае надо с флагом "text/html"

```js
var newNode='<div class="list col-sm" style="border: black;border-style: dashed;border-width: 1px;background-color: #00000012;"> My DIV </div>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(newNode, "text/html").documentElement
var stack = document.getElementById('lol');
stack.appendChild(doc);
```

```html
<div id="lol"></div>
```

Comment: внес  правки   ....